# select dropdown shrinks on first click, while loading options with ajax, but works fine if clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery

the select dropdown of branch name, shrinks when focus is not on bank dropdown. but options are there, just not visible, i have to scroll it, but if i click again. it works fine. i am using ajax here. there should be a dropdown on clicking branch. 
the bank, branch name and ifsc code are all connected from the database
this is html

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Bank<span><font color="red"></font></span></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="bank_id" id="bank_id">
          <c:choose>  
            <c:when test="${bankDetailsEdit.bank_id != 0}">
                <option value="${bankDetailsEdit.bank_id }" >${bankDetailsEdit.bankName }</option>
            </c:when>   
            <c:when test="${bankDetailsEdit.bank_id == 0}">
                <option disabled selected>Select Bank</option>
            </c:when>
          </c:choose>    
                <c:forEach var="bank" items="${bankMasterDetails}">
                    <option value="${bank.bank_id}">${bank.bank_name}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Bank Branch Name<span><font color="red"> </font></span></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="bankBranchId" id="op1" >
                <option value="${bankDetailsEdit.bankBranchId }" >${bankDetailsEdit.bankBranchName }</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>IFSC Code<span><font color="red"> </font></span></label>
            <input type="text" id="ifsc" value="${bankDetailsEdit.ifsc }" name="ifsc" class="form-control input-sm v-disable" readonly>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is script

```
$(document).ready(function(){ /* PREPARE THE SCRIPT */
        $("#bank_id").focus();
        $("#bank_id").on('blur change',function(){ /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */

          var bank_id = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
          var dataString={'bank_id':bank_id}; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */

          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",

                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/broker/bankBranchDetails",
                data : ({
                    'bank_id':bank_id
                }),

                success: function (bankList) {
                    $('#op1').empty();
                    var opt = '<option disabled selected>Select Branch</option>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < bankList.length; i++) {
                        $('#op1').append(opt);
                        opt = new Option(bankList[i].bank_branch_name,bankList[i].bank_branch_id);

                    }

                   },
                   error: function (request, error) {
                      alert("Unable to fetch bank details");
                   }
              });  

        });

        $("#op1").change(function(){ /* WHEN YOU CHANGE AND SELECT FROM THE SELECT FIELD */

              var branch_id = $(this).val(); /* GET THE VALUE OF THE SELECTED DATA */
              var dataString={'branch_id':branch_id}; /* STORE THAT TO A DATA STRING */

              $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",

                    url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/broker/branchIfscDetails",
                    data : ({
                        'branch_id':branch_id
                    }),

                    success: function (data) {
                        var ifsc = data;
                        document.getElementById("ifsc").value=ifsc;

                       },
                       error: function (request, error) {
                          alert("Unable to fetch bank details");
                       }
                  });  

            });

      });
```

Comment: There is no Java in this question. Please note that Java and Javascript are as related as Austria and Australia.

Comment: This is actually a jsp file

Comment: The above html is written in it.